# Non Standard Basis for Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I show that $B = (1, x, \frac 45 x^2 - 2)$ is a basis of $\mathbb P^2$?

I think I should be able to do this without using a change of base matrix, but I'm not really sure how to do this?

Comment: It's enough to show that $B$ is linearly independent, since $P^2$ has dimension three.

Answer (score 2):

We show these polynomials are linearly independent. Since there are $3$ of them, and the whole space has dimension $3$, it follows they form a basis.

Suppose that the linear combination
$$P(x)=a(1)+b(x)+c((4/5)x^2-1/5)$$ is identically $0$. If $c\ne 0$, the coefficient of $x^2$ in $P(x)$ is non-zero, so $P(x)$ cannot be identically $0$.

Thus $c=0$. If $b\ne 0$, the coefficient of $x$ in $P(x)$ is non-zero, so $P(x)$ cannot be identically $0$.

Thus $c=b=0$. From this it follows that $a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\pmatrix { p_1 \\ p_2 \\ p_3}
=
\pmatrix { 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -3/5 & 0 & 4/5}
\pmatrix { 1 \\ x \\ x^2}
$$
The matrix is nonsingular because it is triangular and has no zeros in the diagonal.

If you don't want to use this matrix, consider the subspace $V$ generated by $B$. You already have $1, x \in V$. Now $x^2 = (3/4)p_1+(5/4)p_3 \in V$. So, $V$ is the whole space.